# Docker Continue to Run process in background even after kill

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, devops

I am using docker to run a python script that uses `subprocess` module to run some commands in terminal ,

After Running the script using docker, if i use `ctrl+c` or `kill` command to kill the the process , in my terminal process is getting killed, but process continue to run in background and create logs as well.

I tried running the script directly in my system , and it works fine and after killing it just stop, but when i ran using docker it continue to run in background even after `kill -9 process_id`.

sample code to simulate the issue.

```
import getpass
import subprocess
import os
import signal, time

print('python user: ', getpass.getuser())

def test(i):
    try:
        drop_temp_tbl = subprocess.Popen(f'echo "test">>test.txt;sleep 40; echo "test6{i}">>test.txt;',
                                         shell=True,
                                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        (drop_temp_tbl_stdout, drop_temp_tbl_stderr) = drop_temp_tbl.communicate()
        print('_subprocess_user,', drop_temp_tbl_stdout, '\n', drop_temp_tbl_stderr)
    except Exception as e:
        print('terminate ',os.killpg(os.getpgid(drop_temp_tbl.pid), signal.SIGTERM) )
        print('ERROR', e)


for i in range(2):
    test(i)
```

Docker run command

`` docker run -i --rm -v `pwd`:/code ${docker_id} python_script.py ``

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yf software-properties-common

RUN  apt-get -yq update && \
     apt-get -yqq install \
     openssh-client

COPY ./docker_requirement ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r docker_requirement

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 app
RUN useradd --uid 1000 --gid app --home /app app

USER 1000
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

for above example running through docker will continue to append `test.txt` even after `kill -9 process_id`

Comment: find the docker process with `ps -ef | grep docker` then issue `docker kill <PID>`

Comment: yes this will definitely help to kill background process , but this is also needed a kind of manual intervention .
Actually i am using some job related to this in Jenkins, and  if someone force kill the job even though it continue to run .
then we need to manually kill it . that is hectic if you have thousands of job

Comment: Used your code/Dockerfile and tested it locallly, after I run container and then use `ctrl+c`, container is stopped and I don't see second test message in the log file.

Comment: you can see the code there is 40 sec sleep time, look again after sometime `test.txt` file will be updated